# Using an array to select id for a getElementById in a for statement returns "null"

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using an if.. elseif.. else statement to sort what checkbox is being checked.
The working code looks like this

```
<div class=checkUkelonn>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mandag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Mandag" value="Mandag">Mandag
  <input type="checkbox" id="tirsdag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Tirsdag" value="Tirsdag">Tirsdag
  <input type="checkbox" id="onsdag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Onsdag" value="Onsdag">Onsdag
  <input type="checkbox" id="torsdag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Torsdag" value="Torsdag">Torsdag
  <input type="checkbox" id="fredag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Fredag" value="Fredag">Fredag
  <input type="checkbox" id="lørdag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Lørdag" value="Lørdag">Lørdag
  <input type="checkbox" id="søndag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Søndag" value="Søndag">Søndag
</div>
```

and the script goes like

```
var registrert=[];
if (mandag.checked===true) {
        registrert.push(mandag.value);
    } else {}
    if (tirsdag.checked===true){
        registrert.push(tirsdag.value);
    } else {}
    if (onsdag.checked===true){
        registrert.push(onsdag.value);
    } else {}
    if (torsdag.checked===true){
        registrert.push(torsdag.value);
    } else {}
    if (fredag.checked===true){
        registrert.push(fredag.value);
    } else {}
    if (lørdag.checked===true){
        registrert.push(lørdag.value);
        helg+=1;
    } else {}
    if (søndag.checked===true){
        registrert.push(søndag.value);
        helg+=1;
    } else {};
```

it works. but i feel the code is bulky and excessive.
So i tried replacing the javascript part with the following

```
var ukedag=["\"mandag\"","\"tirsdag\"","\"onsdag\"","\"torsdag\"","\"fredag\"","\"lørdag\"","\"søndag\""];
var dag="",id="",index=0;

for (index = 0; index < ukedag.length;index++) {
    id=ukedag[index];
    alert(id)
    dag = document.getElementById(id);
    alert(dag);
    if (dag.checked===true){
        registrert= push(dag.value);
    } else{}
}
```

when selecting mandag checkbox the 2 alert boxes give me back the following responses
alert(id) gives "mandag" (with double quotes)
alert(dag) gives null (no single or double quotes

now the questions is how can i use an array to select an id in html. the first code snippet works, but seems messy. the other is nicer but i can't seem to get the document.getElemtById to select properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just a tip, in any statement like IF statement or WHILE statement, you dont necessarily have to check if its true literally, you could just do `if (mandag.checked)` which will return the boolean of the `mandag.checked` anyway. Checking for false is just `if (!mandag.checked)`

Comment: You don't need the extra double quotes in your array. Also, your `push` statement is wrong. And you don't need to do `index++` twice.

Comment: "mandag" isn't an id, the id's of your elements are dag1, dag2 ... dag7

Comment: Thanks @Sean. I am still learning this and that absolutly makes for prettier code.

Comment: forgot i had changed id's as a test. will revert to mandag and get back to you all with updated code. sorry

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you. fixed push statement and removed the duplicate index++. 

The alert(dag) goes before it displaying null though, meaning there is something wrong before it, right?

Comment: The other things that are wrong have already been pointed out by others in the comments.

Comment: implementing the changes it now works. Thanks for taking time to look at my buggy code :)

I will make this as solved as soon as I figure out how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to initialize an array to check, you can select all the checked checkbox using `document.querySelectorAll(".checkUkelonn input[type=checkbox]:checked");`. Check the below code and see if it is working for you.

```js
function check() {
  var checkedItems = document.querySelectorAll(".checkUkelonn input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  registrert = [];
  if (checkedItems && checkedItems.length) {
    checkedItems.forEach((element) => {
      registrert.push(element.value);
    });
  }
  console.log(registrert);
}
```

```html
<div class="checkUkelonn">
  <input type="checkbox" id="mandag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Mandag" value="Mandag">Mandag
  <input type="checkbox" id="tirsdag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Tirsdag" value="Tirsdag">Tirsdag
  <input type="checkbox" id="onsdag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Onsdag" value="Onsdag">Onsdag
  <input type="checkbox" id="torsdag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Torsdag" value="Torsdag">Torsdag
  <input type="checkbox" id="fredag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Fredag" value="Fredag">Fredag
  <input type="checkbox" id="lørdag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Lørdag" value="Lørdag">Lørdag
  <input type="checkbox" id="søndag" name="ukedag" placeholder="Søndag" value="Søndag">Søndag
</div>

<button onclick="check()">
check
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with calling `array` and assigning `dag`

here you can check the working code.

```
var ukedag=["mandag","tirsdag","onsdag","torsdag","fredag","lørdag","søndag"];
var dag="", id="", index=0;
for (index = 0; index < ukedag.length;index++) {
  id=ukedag[index];
  alert(id);
  dag = id;
  alert(dag);
  if (dag.checked===true){
    registrert= push(dag.value);
    index++
  }
}
```

check the live: [codepen](https://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/YzwZjXa?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you for the input.

the array was wrong indeed I did not need \", I had set the wrong id's as i was trying to solve it and forgot to reset them and my push statement was wrong (correct is `registrert.push(dag.value))`

Cleaning this out of the code, solved it.

The problem i noticed was `document.getElement.byId(id)` returning null.
removing the `document.getElementById(id)` doesn't really help me resolve this.